# Adding manual split function for validating the xgboost function

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

I have working xgboost model, which reads data and use 80% data for training and 20% for testing.

```
    param = {'num_class':4,'objective':'multi:softmax','eval_metric':['merror'],'max_depth':7,'eta':0.04,'subsample':0.8,'min_child_weight':0.5,'max_delta_step':7,'gamma':2,'lambda':10,'colsample_bytree':0.5}
    model = xgb.train(param,dtrain,420,[(dtrain,'train')],verbose_eval=20)
```

Here I have subsample 0.8, so I believe it will use 80% for training and 20% for testing.

And it generates a classification report at the end to display model results.

Here is the train function where I am passing all data

```
def train(train_data, train_labels):
    os.chdir(working_directory)
    start_time = time.time()

    try:
        model = xgb.Booster({'nthread': 4})
        model.load_model("model_file.bin")
        dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(train_data,label=train_labels)
    except:
        dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(train_data,label=train_labels)
        print('training model.....')
        import pdb
        #pdb.set_trace()
        param = {'num_class':4,'objective':'multi:softmax','eval_metric':['merror'],'max_depth':7,'eta':0.04,'subsample':0.8,'min_child_weight':0.5,'max_delta_step':7,'gamma':2,'lambda':10,'colsample_bytree':0.5}
        model = xgb.train(param,dtrain,420,[(dtrain,'train')],verbose_eval=20)
        print('saving model....')
        model.save_model('model_file.bin')
        print('done!')
        print("Time require in training :", time.time() - start_time)
    #Generate Classification report
    #print("Time require in training :", time.time() - start_time)
    pred = model.predict(dtrain,ntree_limit=420)
    print('generating classification report.....')
    print(classification_report(train_labels,pred))
```

** **What I want to do is, I want to create a manual split option, where I keep 20% data separate for testing and 80% I pass to train function for training. And 20% will be used separately for testing.** **

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test 
    = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)
```

Using this function I can do split, but problem with me is, in my case I am reading `labels` from csv file and `data files` are in separate directory. How can I manage to do split of this? So that I can use both of them separately for training and testing.

full code can be seen here - https://gist.github.com/karimkhanp/95d0fcc307677c5c93af74b1739f53bc

Comment: Referring to the line 44 of your github code, is train_data a list of lists?

Comment: @Muhammadhassan : Yes, it looks like this `data['training_data']
array([[ 1.11110193e-04,  2.90959466e+00,  1.12077673e+01, ...,
         2.41905673e+04,  4.31266306e-01,  1.38257092e-01],
       [ 1.11110223e-04,  2.93560499e+00,  1.51801218e+01, ...,
         2.44699471e+04,  3.38264625e-01,  2.10472647e-01],
       [ 5.09992093e-05, -7.64926923e-01,  9.66387189e-01, ...,
         3.54824331e+03,  5.91370507e-01,  4.52235017e-02]])`